# Which is better to use countdown latch or spring integration to call web service in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-integration

Which approach is better to call web service in parallel. Either to use splitter aggregator pattern or web service chain via gateway using task executor in channel to achieve the parallelism or to use countdown latch and achieve parallelism.
If there are not more than 4 or 5 web services.

Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) component, which let you achieve the same when you use publish-subscriber-channel with an executor.

But yes, actually your question is just for personal opinion. Wait that it will be closed! :-)

Comment: Artem, If there is a need to call multipleweb services then same ws outbound gateway can be configured dynamically for all the web services. Do you think that if multiple request comes in then there can be issues with respect to thread safety.

Comment: Would be better if you elaborate more about " same can be configured " because SI WS outbound gateway can be bound only to one particular service Url.

Comment: So what I am planning to make it generic by making a chain which takes input and gives output and in the chain creating the request using service activator and marshalling it using a jaxb marshaller and then calling wsoutbound gateway taking the url from the header of the message. Hence the same chain can be reused for calling another web service request. Now I have doubt whether this pattern will work for multiple concurrent request.